# Apache Loadbalancing not working viya mod_jk

Tags: apache, load-balancing, httpd.conf, mod-jk

Trying to config a load balancing with apache 2.4 via xampp on Windows 10.

> My workers.proprties

```
worker.list=balancer,stat

worker.instance01.type=ajp13
worker.instance01.host=localhost
worker.instance01.port=8111
worker.instance01.lbfactor=10

worker.instance02.type=ajp13
worker.instance02.host=localhost
worker.instance02.port=8112
worker.instance02.lbfactor=10

worker.instance03.type=ajp13
worker.instance03.host=localhost
worker.instance03.port=8113
worker.instance03.lbfactor=10

worker.balancer.type=lb
worker.balancer.balancer_workers=instance01,instance02,instance03

worker.stat.type=status
```

> my httpd.conf

```
[...]
    AcceptFilter http none
    AcceptFilter https none
    # AJP13 Proxy
    #<IfModule mod_proxy.c>
    #<IfModule mod_proxy_ajp.c>
    #Include "conf/extra/httpd-ajp.conf"
    #</IfModule>
    #</IfModule>
    
        LoadModule jk_module modules/mod_jk.so
        
        JkWorkersFile conf/workers.properties
        
        JkLogFile logs/mod_jk.log
        JkLogLevel emerg
        JkLogStampFormat "[%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y] "
        JkOptions +ForwardKeySize +ForwardURICompat -ForwardDirectories
        JkRequestLogFormat "%w %V %T"
        
        JkMount / balancer
        JkMount /status stat
```

> apache error.log

```
    [Sat Aug 08 23:46:06.681796 2020] [jk:emerg] [pid 17136:tid 600] Error in reading worker properties from 'C:/xampp/apache/conf/workers.properties'
AH00016: Configuration Failed
```

> no entries in mod_jk.log

The module mod_jk.so is located modules, as it should.

**Can anyone help me please?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change below line.

From:

```
worker.balancer.balancer_workers=instance01,instance02,instance03
```

to:

```
worker.balancer.balance_workers=instance01,instance02,instance03
```

Comment: Damn it, I was already desperate.
Super eyes, thank you very much !! I would never have thought of it.